# Copying a string with nulls inside

Tags: c, string, null, null-terminated

I want to copy a string in C (Windows) that contains nulls in it. I need a function to which I will pass buffer length so that the NULL characters will be meaningless. I found StringCbCopy function but it still stops at the first NULL character.

Comment: By the very definition of a string, it is delimited by a NUL, so except for the terminator, there are no NULs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you know the length, use `memcpy()`.

Comment: +1 Exactly. Since you are not dealing with "null-terminated strings", you should not work with functions that expect them. Operate on the "string" as a memory buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick bit of code that may help:

```
char array1[5] = "test", array2[5];
int length = 5;
memcpy(array2, array1, length*sizeof(char));
//the sizeof() is redundant in this because each char is a byte long
//but it is useful if you are working with other datatypes
```

memcpy probably will become your best friend for situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

It should be very easy to write your own function to do this. If you know the length of the string, just create a char[] or char* with the specified length, and copy characters one by one.

Comment: Or don't, and use the C89 function for this -- `memcpy`.